# How to add some code to c# Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have made an installer which contains the exe and dlls, made in using Visual studio the thing is can i add some code to it?

example when it install i just want to run 3-4 lines of code.

1- Get mac address add to database, with a unique key.

And similarly on uninstall remove the mac address from the database .

Is this possible in this current scenario using the default setup project?

Comment: Which mac address? Machines may have multiple network adapters (both real and virtual) and they'll all have different addresses. And it's still possible that someone may replace a network adapter, so changing one or more mac addresses.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever getting the mac address in not mainly my concern it was just to add code to the installer.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that, if you've split this problem down into "get mac address, then add/remove it to a database at appropriate installation times", and you're concentrating on part 2 at the moment, you're currently ignoring a bigger issue for why this solution may not work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i wont be using mac it was just an example :), will use keys generated on runtime something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a [`CustomAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd8h80ez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for your installer. With this you can run a program, script, write a registry key, or whatever. [Here's a simple example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using a custom installer class to show a message during the installation (in VB.NET but easily translatable):

```
Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
  MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
  Dim myInput As String = Me.Context.Parameters.Item("Message")
  If myInput Is Nothing Then
    myInput = "There was no message specified"
  End If
  MsgBox(myInput)
End Sub
```

You would need to follow the steps in the link to fully reproduce the sample.

Comment: [Updated version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.NET installer classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) and wire those up from the default setup project.  You override some methods and then they get called at install/uninstall time.  Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.sanketik.com/index.php/custom-installer-class-to-create-setup-tasks-in-visual-studio-setup-project/) on how to do this.

That said, a lot of people hate these .NET installer classes (and the default setup projects) altogether and implement true Custom Actions using a WIX or InstallShield based project.

Depending on what exactly you want to do and when you want to do it, you also introduce a .NET dependency.  For example, if you are checking for .NET being installed, you won't be able to do this from a .NET custom action if the user does not have .NET already installed.

Adding Custom Actions is a bit of a slippery slope.  Once people realize you can customize the installer, you'll likely be asked to do more and more.  At that point it may make sense to use a more flexible tool (WIX (open source) or InstallShield ($)).